# Angular 6 HttpClient GET response not returning the custom headers

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am new to Angular 6 and have created a new application to replace our existing Angular 1.x application. 
I am making a GET call to the server like so -

```
httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }),
responseType: 'text' as 'json'
};

return this.http.get(this.domain + '/login', this.httpOptions).pipe(
  map((res: HttpResponse<any>) => {
  let myHeader = res.headers.get('X-CSRF-TOKEN');
  return res;
}
```

In my response header I get something like this -

[image]

In my response callback I am trying to get this token info and set it to some storage to pass as header to my future request. However, my response body is an HTML document - which I am receiving using

```
responseType: 'text' as 'json
```

So inside my callback, instead of getting the entire response which includes the headers, I am just getting the HTML document as text. 
[image]

Why am I not getting the complete response with header and all?

Note: I tried removing the responseType altogether - but then I'm always just getting an HttpErrorResponse even though the server returns a 200.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse
```

So I have retained the responseType.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're after the `{observe: 'response'}` option for `HttpClient`:

```
httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }),
  responseType: 'text' as 'json',
  observe: 'response'
};
```

> Now HttpClient.get() returns an Observable of typed HttpResponse rather than just the JSON data.

See [Reading the full response](https://v6.angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response) in the docs.

Comment: Thanks! That was it. The link had all the details I wanted. I've marked the question as answered. However, though I'm getting the complete response now, I'm not getting all the headers. The only ones I'm getting are "content-type", "cache-control", "last-modified", and "expires". I also had to say observe: 'response' as 'body' failing which I got the error "Types of property 'observe' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"body"'". Should I post this as a new question?